# Brackets - Live Preview in chrome even after brackets was uninstalled

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04, adobe-brackets

I uninstalled Brackets from Ubuntu 16.04 using the commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove brackets
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/brackets
```

But now whenever I try to open google chrome, it opens the following window:

[image: Live Preview window even after brackets was uninstalled]

And even the name of the application got changed from Google Chrome to Bootstrap Images - Google Chrome:

[image: Application name changed]

I was building a website using Bootstrap which the explains the reason behind the new name.
Now whenever I open a HTML file, it always opens the live preview window on the first tab.

I can open google chrome normally when I type in the terminal:

```
$ google-chrome-stable
```

How can I fix this?

P.S. I already tried reinstalling chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the brackets live preview integration you need to update this file

```
~/.local/share/applications/chrome.desktop
```

The file will have the following line -

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --user-data-dir=/home/<user>/.config/Brackets/live-dev-profile/Default/ --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --allow-file-access-from-files --temp-profile file:///opt/Brackets/LiveDevelopment/launch.html
```

Which is basically the command that is run for starting chrome.
Remove the`--user-data-dir` and `file:///opt/Brackets/LiveDevelopment/launch.html` plus any other options that you don't need and then start chrome.

Chrome should open without the Brackets live integration.